# Verbose build in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-construction

When trying to build my application, XCode 4 freezes on "compiling source file 1 of ...". I have to force quit.

Is there a way to do a verbose build so I can see on which file it is crashing?

Answer (score 8):

I know this answer is late, anyway I hope it can help somebody with my same issue: look here on current Xcode version 6.1:

[image: XCode 6.1 build log]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the command line xcodebuild tool and see what the output is there. Maybe it will provide some clues on what's going on.